# Java method returns an object of the same class

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with my following code:

```
public class Board {
    private int[][] blocks;
    private  int dim;
    private int hDistance;
    private int mDistance;
    private int indexRow;//row of the empty block;
    private int indexColumn;//column of the empty block;

    public Board(int[][] blocks)                                             
    {       
       dim = blocks.length;
       this.blocks = new int[dim][dim];
       this.blocks = blocks;
       mDistance = manhattan();
       hDistance = hamming();   
    }

    public Board twin()                    
    {
       Board twinBoard = this;

       if(indexRow!=0)
       {
          exch(twinBoard.blocks, 0, 0, 0, 1);//swap(twinBoard.blocks[0][0] with twinBoard.blocks[0][1] 
       }
       else
       {
          exch(twinBoard.blocks, 1, 0, 1, 1);//swap(twinBoard.blocks[1][0] with twinBoard.blocks[1][1] 
       }
       return twinBoard;        
    }
    private void exch(int[][] blocks, int i1, int j1, int i2, int j2)
    {
       int temp;
       temp = blocks[i1][j1];
       blocks[i1][j1] = blocks[i2][j2];
       blocks[i2][j2] = temp;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       int[][] a = {
                {2,0,4},
                {1,5,7},
                {3,6,8}
                };

       Board board1 = new Board(a);
       Board board2 = board1.twin();
    }
}
```

print out `board1.blocks` I got:

2,0,4

5,1,7

3,6,8

Instead of

2,0,4

1,5,7

3,6,8

How did `board1.blocks` get swapped? And how can I only have `board2.block` swapped, and `board1.block` remain the same as before?

Comment: `twinBoard` needs to be a new object, you have this problem because you use this. So both `board1` and `board2` are the same object

Comment: As a side comment `this.blocks = new int[dim][dim];` this makes no sense, since in the following line you are doing `this.blocks = blocks;`. There is no point in creating a matrix that you will never use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
Board twinBoard = this;
```

Your code's "twin board" is *not* a different board: it is the same board as `this`, so any changes made to `twinBoard` are reflected in `this` as well.

To fix this problem, define a new constructor for copying the board:

```
private Board(Board other) {
    ...
}
```

Inside this constructor you need to make a copy of the `board`, and set `hDistance`, `mDistance`, and other fields to their values in the `other` board. Now you can use this constructor to make a twin board:

```
Board twinBoard = new Board(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did work. Interestingly, if I add this.blocks = board.blocks inside the constructor private Board(Board other), it doesn't work. If I add for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<dim; j++)
            {
                this.blocks[i][j] = board.blocks[i][j];
            }
        }  It works.

Comment: @popcornhex That's expected - if you assign `blocks` without copying, you are "aliasing"  `blocks` rather than the `Board`, but the end result is the same.